# Best way to omit Lua standard libraries?

Tags: c, lua

What is the best way to remove or omit a Lua standard library package?  For example remove the [os library functions](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.8) in a particular environment.  The project in question is building Lua from the source files so I *can* edit the source, although I would rather do it through the API if possible.

Comment: See also [How can I create a secure Lua sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224708/how-can-i-create-a-secure-lua-sandbox)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

See the file `luaconf.h` in the source kit for easy access to most compile-time configuration such as the actual type used for `lua_Number`.

See the file `linit.c` in the source kit for the list of core libraries that are loaded by calling `luaL_openlibs()`.

Common practice is to copy that file to your application's source, and modify it to suit your needs, calling that copy's `luaL_openlibs()` in place of the core version. If you are compiling Lua privately and not linking to one of the pre-built binaries of the library, then you can find a method to do the equivalent that suits your needs.

Of course, you also don't need to compile or link to the sources for any library (such as `os`, found in `loslib.c`) that you choose to leave out of `luaL_openlibs()`.

The only library that you probably can't leave out completely is the base library that provides things like `pairs()`, `ipairs()`, `pcall()`, `tostring()`, and lots more that can be really inconvenient to do without. When porting to an environment where some of these are problematic, it is usually a good idea to look closely at its implementation in `lbaselib.c` and either trim features from it or reimplement them to suit your needs.

**Edit:**

Another approach to including a different list of libraries in the interpreter is to not call `luaL_openlibs()` at all. Although provided as a convenience, like all of the auxiliary library, `luaL_openlibs()` is not mandatory. Instead, explicitly open just the libraries you want.

[Chapter 5](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5) of the reference manual talks about this:

> To have access to these libraries, the
>   C host program should call the
>   `luaL_openlibs` function, which opens
>   all standard libraries. Alternatively,
>   it can open them individually by
>   calling `luaopen_base` (for the basic
>   library), `luaopen_package` (for the
>   package library), `luaopen_string` (for
>   the string library), `luaopen_table`
>   (for the table library), `luaopen_math`
>   (for the mathematical library),
>   `luaopen_io` (for the I/O library),
>   `luaopen_os` (for the Operating System
>   library), and `luaopen_debug` (for the
>   debug library). These functions are
>   declared in `lualib.h` and should not be
>   called directly: you must call them
>   like any other Lua C function, e.g.,
>   by using `lua_call`.

That last sentence is occasionally the source of trouble, since older versions of Lua did not have that restriction. Each of the individual module's `luaopen_xxx()` functions follows the same protocol used by the `require` function. It should be passed a single argument: a string containing the name by which the module is known. The exception is the base module, which is passed an empty string because it has no actual name.

Here's a function that creates a new Lua state and opens only the base and package libraries:

```
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"

lua_State *CreateBasicLua() {
    lua_State *L;

    L = luaL_newstate();
    if (L) {
        lua_pushcfunction(L, luaopen_base);
        lua_pushstring(L, "");
        lua_call(L, 1, 0);
        lua_pushcfunction(L, luaopen_package);
        lua_pushstring(L, LUA_LOADLIBNAME);
        lua_call(L, 1, 0);
    }
    return L;
}
```

It returns the new `lua_State` on success, or `NULL` on failure.

Comment: This does appear to be the correct way.  It is too bad we have to edit a c file in the Lua source (or a copy in your project) to configure the standard libs.

Comment: I added a code fragment demonstrating an alternative to editing linit.c to get the customization you want.

Comment: Nice addition I would up it again if I could.

Comment: Why are you using "lua_pushcfunction" at the same time as "luaopen_<libname>"? This is redundant as far as I'm concerned.

You can just call "luaopen_<libname>(L);" and it'll work just fine. Then you don't need to do "lua_call(L, 1, 0);" each time you load one!

Comment: In short, because the manual says to do it this way. "These functions are declared in lualib.h and should not be called directly: you must call them like any other Lua C function, e.g., by using lua_call." (Lua Reference Manual, Chapter 5, pg 65). The luaopen_xxx() functions are promised that they are called like any other C function, with a clean stack that has room for the usual number of temporaries. Calling it directly does not let the core make those guarantees.

Comment: Is it possible for a Lua script to get access to an unloaded library? Maybe by using require? It doesn't sound possible, but this is not 100% clear to me.

Comment: Using `require"foo"` only works if some DLL reachable via the patterns in `package.cpath` contains a function named `luaopen_foo()` that behaves as expected when called. The base libraries are not found by default in any such DLL, as they were compiled in to the Lua core. However, it may be possible to load them anyway using `package.loadlib()` if you know where to look. There are also 3rd-party modules such as alien and ffi that can provide for calling arbitrary functions in any DLL that might be able to do the trick. In short, be careful what you let a script call.

Comment: The triplets in this code sample (pushcfunction/pushstring/call) is basically a shortened version of luaL_requiref(), which should probably be used if you're on 5.2. See lauxlib.c in the lua source tree

Answer (score 10):

Let's say you only want to open the `base` and `package` libraries. In Lua 5.2, the most concise way is

```
luaL_requiref(L, "_G", luaopen_base, 1);
luaL_requiref(L, "package", luaopen_package, 1);
lua_pop(L, 2);
```

This is how the luaL_openlibs function in `linit.c` works, except that it loads everything.

Comment: Good answer, the accepted answer is more lua 5.1 style, while yours is good for lua 5.2. Currently looking for a way to reconcile lua 5.2 and luajit. (to anyone interested, just compare linit.c from 5.1 and 5.2, it'll become really obvious)

Comment: This is the approach that the official documentation for 5.3 suggests. http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6

Answer (score 3):

I think that post answers your question, but a little more info on the subject.
Be aware you can also just 'nil' entire tables.

So in your example the "os" lib you can do a "os = nil" then poof!, the "os" lib/table is gone.
Doing a "os.time()" after this example would return an error for a now nonexistent lib/table.
Furthermore if you just wanted to nix the "time" method alone in "os" you could just do "os.time = nil".

Comment: be aware that if that's the only thing you do, the user can easily get it back with `os = require("os")`. You must disallow library loading!

Comment: Also, if the goal is faster startup time for the application, then that won't help.