# C++ Factory using lua

Tags: c++, refactoring, lua, factory

I had a script with:

- Custom language used only for data
- Was loaded using a Script class from C++
- I had tags like Type, etc
- An interface to get a value for a tag - Script::GetValue(Tag, T& value)

The script was used like this:

```
Script* script("someFile");
script->GetValue("Type", type);
Object* obj = CreateObject(type);
obj->Load(script);
```

Where Load functions from object was used to load the rest of obj parameters.
Now I changed the script language to lua. My questions is:

Should I keep this way of creating objects(use lua only for data) or should I expose the factory in lua and use it from lua, something like this(in lua):

```
CreateObject("someType")
SetProperty(someObj, someProperty, someValue)
```

First of all I want to know which is faster, first or second approach. Do you have other suggestions? Because I'm refactoring this part I'm open to other suggestions. I want to keep lua because is fast, easy to integrate, and small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may allow your script environment to create C++ objects or not, depending on your needs.
tolua++ uses all the metatable features to allow a very straightforward manipulation of your c++ types in lua.

For example, this declaration :

```
// tolua_begin
class SomeCppClass
{
public:
   SomeCppClass();
   ~SomeCppClass();

   int some_field;
   void some_method();
};
// tolua_end
```

Will automatically generate the lua bindings to allow this lua scipt :

```
#!lua
-- obj1 must be deleted manually
local obj1 = SomeCppClass:new() 
-- obj1 will be automatically garbage collected 
local obj2 = SomeCppClass:new_local()

obj1.some_field = 3 -- direct access to "some_field"
obj2:some_method() -- direct call to "some_method"

obj1:delete()
```

The advantage of this technique is that your lua code will ve very consistent with the relying C++ code. See http://www.codenix.com/~tolua/tolua++.html

Answer (score 0):

In situations like that, I prefer to setup a bound C function that takes a table of parameters as an argument. So, the Lua script would look like the following.

```
CreateObject{
    Type = "someType"'
    someProperty = someValue,
    -- ...
}
```

This table would be on top of the stack in the callback function, and all parameters can be accessed by name using [lua_getfield](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_getfield).

You may also want to investigate [sandboxing your Lua environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224708/how-can-i-create-a-secure-lua-sandbox).

Answer (score 0):

The first approach would most likely be faster, but the second approach would probably result in less object initialization code (assuming you're initializing a lot of objects).  If you choose the first approach, you can do it manually.  If you choose the second approach you might want to use a binding library like [Luabind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind.html) to avoid errors and speed up implementation time, assuming you're doing this for multiple object types and data types.

The simplest approach will probably be to just use Lua for data; if you want to expose the factory and use it via Lua, make sure it's worth the effort first.