# LuaInterface - how-to restrict access to .Net classes?

Tags: c#, scripting, lua, luainterface

I'm trying to embed some Lua scripting functionality in my C# app by using LuaInterface 2.0.3. This is working just fine so far, but I can't figure out how to restrict access to only few specified .Net classes. By default, all .Net libraries are directly accessible through "luanet" and Lua scripts are free to open new windows or access the file system.

e.g. this Lua script will open a new Window:

```
   Form = luanet.System.Windows.Forms.Form
   mainForm = Form()
   mainForm:ShowDialog()
```

Freedom of scripting is great and all, but this is likely to interfere with the hosting app and has some security-related implications I'm not too fond of. Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: It's possible that this would get a better response on Games Development, http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/. It is something that game devs are more likely to have done in the past, and appears to be about game development anyway.

Comment: A less specific question on sandboxing Lua, which may point you in the right direction, is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224708/how-can-i-create-a-secure-lua-sandbox

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```lua
--make a table for all the classes you want to expose
safeClasses = {}
--store all the ones you want
safeClasses.Form = luanet.System.Windows.Forms.Form
--etc...

--remove access to LuaInterface
luanet = nil
package.loaded.luanet = nil
--prevent future packages from being loaded
require = nil
package.loadlib = nil
```

You could also do this in reverse, removing the global and stored instances of LuaInterface first and then doing all the work through a local reference (which all code in the rest of the [block](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.4.2) can use):

```lua
--get a local reference to LuaInterface without clobbering the name
local luainterface = luanet

--delete the global reference to it
luanet = nil

--also delete it from the package store and disable package loading
package.loaded.luanet = nil
require = nil
package.loadlib = nil

--put luanet back locally at its original name (for convenience)
local luanet = luainterface 

--make a table for all the classes you want to expose
safeClasses = {}
--store all the ones you want
safeClasses.Form = luanet.System.Windows.Forms.Form
--etc...
```

(You can avoid the three-step name-preservation dance above (`local luainterface=luanet; luanet=nil; local luanet=luainterface`) by localizing directly to `luanet` and then deleting the global through the `_G` reference to the global table:

```lua
local luanet=_G.luanet
_G.luanet = nil
```

I just chose not to as a matter of personal preference.)

Comment: Only had a quick look at it, but this looks excellent already. I guess, my error was to assume this has to be done in C# by somehow setting up or configuring the Lua interpreter differently - didn't realize the sandboxing could be done directly in Lua.

Comment: Tested it in my app - this is **exactly** what I was looking for. Combined with this [link](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes) article I should now be able to construct a proper sandbox for my Lua scripts. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about how exactly you would go about it, but the first step should be hosting it in an extra [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx). With that extra appdomain, you have granular control of what modules can be used and which can't, however, it will add extra work to get data moved between your main program and the script.

The `AssemblyLoad`/`AssemblyResolve` events should be your first stop.

Comment: I don't think this'll be performant enough exactly because of that "extra work". Lua is supposed to drive game logic such as AI or mission scripts... not sure if cross-AppDomain communication would be up for that task, but I have little experience with that, so... yeah. :/