# Lua and Luainterface, use not registered classes from Lua?

Tags: c#, class, lua, bind

Im using the LuaInterface for C#.

In my C# project i got the file Program.cs

which uses the namespace Test and the class is called Program.

In the class Program, i got the method PrintTest().

How do i reach that method from Lua?
I have tried something like this:

luanet.Test.Program:PrintTest();

But lua says "No such method".

I have been looking at this thread: [LuaInterface - how-to restrict access to .Net classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171381/luainterface-how-to-restrict-access-to-net-classes) and managed to create a form like he does, so the problem only occurs with my own custom classes.

---

Okey. The problem seems to be that the method PrintTest is static. If i make it non-static it works, but how do I do if I want it to be static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It usually looks something like this:

```
luanet.load_assembly("YourAssembly")
local Test  = luanet.import_type("Test.Program")
local test = Test()
test.PrintTest()
```

Comment: Forgot to say that the method PrintTest is static.

Im trying the code you posted but getting an error on row 2. It says No such type.

Comment: Did you adjust line 1 to include the name of your assembly? Are you loading this via the LuInterface runner, or are you hosting LuaInterface in your application?

Answer (score 1):

Despite the age of this thread, I had the same question and was able to find a satisfactory answer.

As of LuaInterface 1.5.1, to call a static method on a type, you simply use the dot operator.

ex:

```
luanet.load_assembly("AssemblyName")
local Test = luanet.import_type("Test.Program")
Test.PrintTest()
```

Reference: https://github.com/megax/LuaInterface