# Lua Sandbox with special functions which leak

Tags: lua, sandbox

I am trying to use [How can I create a secure Lua sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224708/how-can-i-create-a-secure-lua-sandbox) to build my own leaky sandbox.

I am trying to create a Lua sandbox where some Lua functions can access some other Lua functions outside the sandbox. For example I want my sandbox to have a special "display" function which can call "print" but not have "print" in the sandbox too.

The main problem is that I am trying to build a sandbox within an already large codebase, so I cannot nil away functions.

How is this possible?

The solution has to be a pure Lua function due to no fault of mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a sandbox, you do it by cherry picking functions and values from a larger environment to create a new sandbox environment. You do not need to destroy or "nil out" anything in the original environment.

1. Create your sandbox environment by cherry picking functions and values
2. Load a script (this compiles it and returns it as a function to call)
3. Set the environment of the script to the sandbox environment
4. Execute the script in the sandbox

So,

```
local script = loadstring "display(math.log(2, 3))"
local env = {display = print, math = math, string = string}
setfenv(script, env)
pcall(script)
```

prints

```
0.69314718055995
```

whereas

```
local script = loadstring "print(math.log(2, 3))"
local env = {display = print, math = math, string = string}
setfenv(script, env)
pcall(script)
```

fails with

```
false   [string "print(math.log(2, 3))"]:1: attempt to call global 'print' (a nil value)
```

Comment: This seems close to what I want. I'll try it out and see if it works the way I need.

Answer (score 1):

Does it specifically need to call the Lua standard library `print` function? Can you instead emulate the functionality of `print`? Because that would be the easiest way.

However, if you want to have a wrapper around `print`, there are two ways to do it: with pure Lua code, and with C/C++ code.

The pure Lua solution is as follows. Note that this should be done before loading any external scripts. First, open the Lua standard library that has `print` in it. Then run this Lua script:

```
local internal_print = print

return function(...)
    --Do display logic.
    internal_print(...) --Or whatever else you want.
end
```

This will return the "display" function. You can store it in a global variable called `display` if you like, or called something else.

After that, you can `nil` out the `print` global variable, thus making it almost entirely inaccessible.

If you want to do it from C/C++, it's very similar. First, as before, you register the Lua standard library that includes `print`, so that you can get the function for it. Then, you use `lua_getglobal(L, "print")` to get the `print` function and push it onto the stack. Next, you register your C/C++ function using using `lua_pushcclosure`. But you want to specify one upvalue, which Lua pops off the stack at registration time.

And now your registered function is on the stack, waiting to be pushed into a Lua variable or global table entry.

**Warning:** the Lua debug library can poke at upvalues and thus get the `print` function from your new function. So if you want perfect security, get rid of `debug.getupvalue`.

Comment: The "print" was only an easy example to explain the concept. Also, I cannot nil out the old "print" because there is extensive code which accesses it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Build your sandbox (or multiple sandboxes if they each have different requirements) and move the untrusted code into the sandbox one piece at a time. In my quick cli tests, both 5.1 and 5.2 will run functions that were defined outside of the sandbox without modification. To use Doug's example, assume `display` is part of your pre-existing code that uses `print`:

```lua
-- 5.1
local function display(...)
  print(...)
end
local script = loadstring "display(math.log(2, 3))"
local env = {display = display, math = math, string = string}
setfenv(script, env)
print(pcall(script))

-- 5.2
local function display(...)
  print(...)
end
local script = loadstring "display(math.log(2, 3))"
local e=_ENV
_ENV={display = display, math = math, string = string}
e.print(e.pcall(script))
_ENV=e
```

Note that in both of the above examples, the `display` function is using `print` without modification to that code since you were not in the sandbox when this function was created.

In the past, I've stored a local pointer to the un-sandboxed environment, but I can't reproduce the situation where that's needed in my quick cli tests. If you can come up with an example, I can probably come up with a workaround that doesn't require the `e` variable. Here's an example of that code using 5.2:

```
local e=_ENV

for k,v in e.pairs(value) do
-- iterate
end
```

another example, for my read only table code, I'm again using the `e`:

```
function ro_table (t)
  local t = t
  if t then
    return e.setmetatable({}, 
      { __index=t, 
        __newindex= function(_,_,_) e.error ("Attempt to modify read-only table") end, 
      })
  else
    return nil
  end
end
```