# Create Lua (5.2 +) sandbox from C

Tags: lua

I'm trying to setup a sandbox with support for only a limited number of functions.
Prior to Lua 5.2, this could be accomplished by the setfenv function. In 5.2 and above, as this function is not available, I guess you have to do this differently. There are some examples to do this from Lua itself [Sandboxing in Lua 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280124/sandboxing-in-lua-5-2]). Any sample code to do it from C with a simple sandbox that supports, for instance only the print function?

Answer (score 0):

See [luaB_loadfile](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lbaselib.c.html#luaB_loadfile) and [load_aux](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lbaselib.c.html#load_aux) for how to set `_ENV` from C. The key point is to set the sandbox as the first upvalue of the Lua function when it is loaded, before it is run.