# How would someone create a preemptive scheduler for the Lua VM?

Tags: lua, virtual-machine

I've been looking at lua and lvm.c.  I'd very much like to implement an interface to allow me to control the VM interpreter state.

Cooperative multitasking from within lua would not work for me (user contributed code)

The debug hook gets me only about 50% of the way there, instruction execution limits, but it raises an exception which just crashes the running lua code - but I need to be able to tweak it even further.

I want to create a system where 10's of thousands of lua user scripts are running - individual threads would not work, and the execution limits would cause headache for beginning developers, I'm going to control execution speeds too. but ultimately

```
while true do

end
```

will execute forever, and I really don't care that it is.

Any ideas, help or other implementations that I could look at?

EDIT: This is not about sandboxing pretend I'm an expert in that field for this conversation

EDIT: I do not want to use an internally ran lua code coroutine based controller.

EDIT: I want to run one thread, and manage a large number of user contributed lua scripts, an external process level control mechansim would not scale at all.

Answer (score 2):

<s>You can search for Lua Sandbox implementations; for example, this [wiki page](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes) and [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224708/how-can-i-create-a-secure-lua-sandbox) provide some pointers. Note that most of the effort in sandboxing is focused on not allowing you to execute bad code, but not necessarily on preventing infinite loops. For better control you may need to combine Lua sandboxing with something like [LXC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC) or [cpulimit](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/).</s> (not relevant based on the comments)

If you are looking for something Lua-based, lightweight, but not necessarily 100% foolproof, then you can try running your client code in a separate coroutine and set a debug hook on that coroutine that will be triggered every N-th line. In that hook you can check if the process you are running exceeded its quotes. You also need to take care of new coroutines started as those need to have their own hooks set (you either need to disable coroutine.create/wrap or to replace them with something that sets the debug hook you need).

The code in this case may look like:

```
local coro = coroutine.create(client_func)
debug.sethook(coro, debug_hook, "l", 1000) -- trigger hook on every 1000th line
```

It's not foolproof, because it may block on some IO operation and the debug hook will not help there.

[Edit based on updated question and comments]

Between "no lua code coroutine based controller" and "no external process control mechanism" I don't think you are left with much choice. It may be that your only option is to run one VM per user script and somehow give ticks to those VMs (there was a recent question on SO on this, but I can't find it). Before going this route, *I* would still try to do this with coroutines (which should scale to tens of thousands easily; Tir claims [supporting 1M active users](http://sheddingbikes.com/posts/1289384533.html) with coroutine-based architecture).

The mechanism would roughly look like this: you install the debug hook as I shown above and from that hook you yield back to your controller, which then decides what other coroutine (user script) to resume. I have this very mechanism working in the [Lua debugger](https://github.com/pkulchenko/MobDebug) I've been developing (although it only does it for one client script). This doesn't protect you from IO calls that can block and for that you may still need to have a watchdog at the VM level to see if it's been blocked for longer than needed.

If you need to serialize and deserialize running code fragments that preserve upvalues and such, then [Pluto](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PlutoLibrary) is probably your only option.

Comment: Sandboxing is not what I was interested in, in-fact I  might not care if they can include external libraries or anything - well I do, but I'll cross that bridge when I get there (sandboxing in lua, is an arguably a trivial exercise, that some people don't get, but lets assume I do)

Comment: I don't think LXC and cpulimit would scale to the 10's of thousands, I suggested I want to run (runnning slowly which is not an issue) - lets say I grow to 1,000,000 lua scripts running simultaneously.  does your recommendation still stand in that scenario?

Comment: The debug_hook solution I don't know that I could create an effective solution from within a coroutine controller script - I would rather manage them from within C. for a few reasons - one of which would be "process teleportation" or something, where I can take the running lua script, and memory map pause it, pickle it and send it to another process or even computer - to allow scaling of this to a very massive amount of scripts concurrently running, and "load balanced".

Comment: Honestly, I feel that your response as informative as it was, to someone who may not know much about lua, It fell short of paying attention to what I was asking about. Frankly offered solutions that I mentioned in the question I was not interested in.

Comment: @Prozacgod: updated the post. I'm sorry you feel I answered a different question from the one you asked. You made some changes that helped clarify what you want to do, and you asked for ideas, which I provided.

Comment: hey no worries man, I realize my response might have not been the greatest. I did feel that I had to respond to each suggested seperately.  Which was probably a bit annoying.  I need to look at the Pluto patches to the execution of the VM it might provide me some insight.  Anyway this is all a big toy project that may or may not bear fruit, I've even considered implementing my own VM entirely, but I do believe that what I'm trying to do needs to be at the C level, and having the ability to step the VM seems the best solution.

Comment: Pluto pans out to being something I need to "keep in my back pocket" - because I want/neeed to address the persistence situation at some point.  But not just yet,  I had thought it might muck with VM code, but it seems that the Lua VM is a big black box of unknowns... might as well be labeled with a sign that says "beyond here lies dragons"

Answer (score 0):

Look at implementing `lua_lock` and `lua_unlock`. 
http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/llimits.h.html#lua_lock

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at lulu. It is lua VM written on lua. It's for Lua 5.1
For newer version you need to do some work. But it's then you really can make a schelduler.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, 
https://github.com/amilamad/preemptive-task-scheduler-for-lua
I maintain this project. It,s a non blocking preemptive scheduler for running lua code. Suitable for long running game scripts.