# Handling StackOverflowException in Lua

Tags: c#, .net, lua

I'm making an IRC bot in C#, and want to have Lua be executable via a command. I already have this working, and have overcome some basic obstacles, but now I'm having a larger problem with a StackOverflowException; My friend gave me some Lua code to run, which every time seems to cause a StackOverflowException, no matter how hard I try to prevent it.

```
print(string.find(string.rep("a", 2^20), string.rep(".?", 2^20)))
```

So, with this being executed using LuaInterface (LuaInterface 2.0.0.16708 to be precise) - I get a StackOverflowException in my code and I don't seem to be able to fix this, looking at some previous questions.

I know parsing code before executing it to predict stack overflows is hard, so I don't know how I would circumvent this. I have already tried multi-threading (which solved a previous problem where yielding code wouldn't return control back to C#) but this does not seem to help.

Comment: What is that code segment supposed to do? Doing pattern matching with a 2MB pattern is not going to perform well, and that pattern simply matches all strings up to 1MB in size, so its not even useful.

Comment: I noticed that, but that appears to create a stack overflow, which crashes my program. I don't know what the code is meant to do either - I just told some people in the IRC channel I was in to run some snippets of code, to see if they could break it, and one of them happened to do that.

Comment: Oh, so you want to sandbox your program against code such as this? Well, that's not a trivial task. There's lots of things that you need to protect against, such as infinite loops, access to IO/system calls, etc.

Comment: That's the problem - I don't want to really go down that route due to how many ways it can be done in Lua. If I did manage to do it, I would more than likely remove half of the use of the language. I guess I'll just have to give fair warning to the users of my bot that the Lua command is unstable and could cause a crash?

Comment: Well, what if a user did `os.system("rm -rf /")` or some other malicious command? You'll have far more to worry about than a crash.

Comment: I already disabled the os library entirely; I could forsee something like that happening anyway. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around that particular error use Lua 5.2.2 or newer. The case is [a reported bug](http://www.lua.org/bugs.html#5.2.1-1) that got fixed in the version 5.2.2. It gives "pattern too complex" error instead.

And as far as sandboxing is concered why not fashion it after [the Lua live demo](http://www.lua.org/demo.html) as suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1225373/100353)? I don't know how secure it is but I'd presume the authors have both the incentive and capability of making it as secure as possible. The sources can be found from [here](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#demo).

Comment: Darn! I was trying to avoid this because of _ENV; I prefer getfenv and setfenv and I'm sure the people I know do too.

Comment: Heh, life is just a string of choices you are forced to make :)