# Restrict access to all .Net classes in Nlua

Tags: c#, lua, sandbox, nlua

Yes, I'm well aware of the other questions like this, [but the other (almost the same) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224708/how-can-i-create-a-secure-lua-sandbox) is for an older version of `NLua`.

Making the question simple, how do I completely sandbox `Nlua`? I want a single class `Foo` to be the only class available to `Nlua`. How can I do this, either C# side or Lua side?

*Note*

`Foo` will have methods that use other namespaces, I don't think it matters though.

Comment: If you've found another question that you think is "almost the same", it would benefit this question immensely if you *linked to it* rather than expecting us to magically find the same one.

Comment: Sorry, editing the link now.