# Lua - How would I break meta tables or make them unuseable?

Tags: lua, metatable

So in my game most exploiters are using metatables to stop bans and I would like to break them, I dont use them and it would only hurt the exploiters. Even if this breaks other parts of lua I can and will fix it but this needs to stop and this is my best bet.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224708/how-can-i-create-a-secure-lua-sandbox

Comment: Sadly sandboxing might help but checking functions wont help because they have a function named newcclosure that closes a function to make sure the game cant detect it, because it sandboxes it in c

Comment: @James: `lua_pushcclosure` is a Lua API call written in C (or a language that speaks C). The only way "exploiters" would be able to call it is if they're writing DLLs or something that your code dynamically loads. If you're dynamically loading *binary executables* directly into your game, security is just not a reasonable possibility. If they can make direct calls into the Lua API, they can easily hijack all kinds of things: every global function, the Lua registry, etc.

Comment: My game uses the engine named ROBLOX which allows this behsvior and its unreasonable to get your idea added and live, sadly, so if you have a way to break metatables it would help.

Comment: Whay about `setmetatable = nil`?

Comment: They also have getrawmetatable which grabs the meta table of the game, however I could do what the first answer here was and just set the games metatable to not your business and it will do exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From *Programming in Lua, 4th Edition*, chapter 20:

> The functions `setmetatable` and `getmetatable` also use a metafield, in this case to protect metatables. **Suppose we want to protect our sets, so that users can neither see nor change their metatables.** If we set a `__metatable` field in the metatable, getmetatable will return the value of this field, whereas setmetatable will raise an error:

```
mt.__metatable = "not your business"

s1 = Set.new{}
print(getmetatable(s1))     --> not your business
setmetatable(s1, {})
    stdin:1: cannot change protected metatable
```

So, your answer? Set the `__metatable` field to prevent access to a table’s metatable. Do that for all tables that you need to protect.

Comment: @James Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please click the checkbox to mark the answer as accepted and upvote it if you find it useful.

Comment: @James: Note that this will not prevent someone from using the C API function `lua_setmetatable` to change it.