# Lua strange behaviour with _ENV

Tags: lua

Can anybody explain why lua 5.3.5 acts this way?

```
a="global"
local b="local"

function problem(_ENV)
    a="fn_a"
    b="fn_b"
end

problem{}
print(_VERSION)
print("a",a)
print("b",b)

--[[ https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo output:
Lua 5.3
a       global
b       fn_b
]]
```

Why local variable can be changed after _ENV changed? Is it bug or feature?

Comment: Roughly speaking, locals have priority over upvalues which have priority over globals.

Comment: Locals are not in the environment; They are in the chunk (compilation unit). So, it's a feature.

Comment: If you are attempting to consume user-provided code, do research [Lua sandboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1225373/2226988).

Comment: Sandbox has the same problem

        local b
    
        a="global"
        b="local"
    
        function fn()
          a="fn_a"
          b="fn_b"
        end
    
        print(a,b)
        run_sandbox(sandbox_env,fn)
        print(a,b)

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** How to eliminate all upvalues?
**A:**

```
a="global"
local b="local"

-- load() actually eliminates all upvalues :-)
no_problem = assert(load[[
    return function (_ENV)
        a="fn_a"
        b="fn_b"
    end
]])()

no_problem{}
print(_VERSION)
print("a",a)  -->  a    global
print("b",b)  -->  b    local
```

Comment: It illiminates upvalues only inside load block but if I call some other function from load block the behaviour will be the same. It can modify parents state. So only io.popen or special c function that create different lua context can truly separate code.

Comment: @SergeyKovalev - You can use `load` block inside another `load` block ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating [upvalue](http://www.lua.org/pil/6.1.html) with the following code:

```
local b="local"
function problem(_ENV)
    b="fn_b"
end
```

During parsing of the function interpreter detects, that function refers to local variable from one of encompassing scopes that are visible from within the function and thus links it directly. Access to local variables precedes lookup of globals in the `_ENV`. If you put `local b="local"` after the function definition, it will not be altered by function calls.

Comment: How to eliminate all upvalues?

Comment: @SergeyKovalev Upvalues cannot be "eliminated". Simply don't reference them.