# Is there a way to redirect io.open to load a file from a custom function in lua?

Tags: lua

I am using Lua embedded.  In my case, I'd like to load files from a fake in memory file system (based on a .zip file), not the real file system.

To accomplish this, I think I need to to redirect/override all of the internal `fopen` calls to something that only looks inside the .zip file.  That doesn't seem possible.  Is it?

[How can I create a secure Lua sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224708/how-can-i-create-a-secure-lua-sandbox)

Here's a quick example:

This code will open a text file and read the contents into a local variable.  Internally, it seems to use `fopen()`, which means that it will use the real filesystem only.

```
local f = io.open('filename.txt')
local t = f:read("*all")
f:close()
```

Instead, I want this to internally call into my "fake" filesystem and I'll return the contents of the file from the fake filesystem.

I have already been able to accomplish something like this for loading .lua files only.  That worked by adding a custom searcher/loader which loaded files from the .zip file.  Now, `require("something.lua")` only loads from the fake filesystem, which is perfect.

However, `load()`, `dofile()` and `loadfile()` still work and use `fopen()`.  I am currently nil'ing them out until I can find a better solution.

```
load = nil
dofile = nil
loadfile = nil
```

At some level, I think I really want to redirect all the filesystem calls somewhere else.

Regardless, I narrowed the scope for this SO question to just ask about `io.open`.  Should I be replacing/redirecting `io.open` in lua with my own so that it loads from my fake filesystem. I guess by extension, would I then re-define the  `io` namespace?

Comment: Yes, redefine io.open.